# Can't import specific modules in embedded Python

Tags: python, objective-c, import

I'm running an embedded Python interpreter in Obj-C. I can run Python scripts just fine, but when I try to import certain standard modules, I get `ImportError: No module named random`, for instance.

However, I can import certain other modules. My investigations has given me this list so far:

Can:

- import sys
- import math
- import datetime
- import time

Can't:

- import random
- import re
- import cmath
- import numbers
- import string

This is from a python file enclosed in a package, imported via PyImport_Import ('package.module'). There is one extension module loaded via Py_InitModule.

This is on Python 2.7.0 - is there any reason some of these modules are available and others not?

Comment: Perhaps those modules just haven't been included in the port you're running? At a glance, those modules could all require compiled components (certainly re and cmath do) which might not have been ported.

Comment: Good find. Turns out that I wasn't including the Python standard library (those funny files in /pylib...). Now I have random running, but loading it breaks in os.py. But that's for another question!

Comment: Any chance you could share how you get the embedded python interpreter running in obj-c - I keep running into similar problems as you

Answer (score 0):

Thomas K set me on the right track, even though the problem was the completely opposite.

My Python setup was lacking the standard Python library - the part written in Python (usually distributed through /Library, /Lib or /pylib in the distribution. Once those files were added to my application, all of it imported fine.

So, the link between the importable and non-importable modules above were that the importable were written as Python extensions in C, whereas the non-importable are written in pure Python.